# Bayes formula question and joint probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If $Z=\min\{X,Y\}$ and $W$ is $1$ if $Z=X$ but $0$ when $Z=Y$; $X,Y$ independent random variables. What would be the procedure to compute joint probability $(Z,W)$?

I think I can compute the $Z$ distribution using $P(Z\leq z)$. Then I could compute $P(Z\leq z | W= 0)=\displaystyle\frac{P(Y\leq Z\cap Y\leq X)}{P(Y\leq X)}.$

And $P(Z\leq z | W= 1)=\displaystyle\frac{P(Y\leq Z\cap X\leq Y)}{P(X\leq Y)}$.

Now are both $X,Y$ are exponential distribution with parameters $a,b$ would it be correct to say that $P(Y\leq X)=ab\int_0^\infty\int_0^x e^{-ax} e^{-by}dydx$ and $P(X\leq Y)=ab\int_0^\infty\int_0^x e^{-ax} e^{-by}dxdy$ ?

Having computed  $P(Z\leq z | W= 0)$ and  $P(Z\leq z | W= 1)$ what would be the joint probability? The cases I'm familiar are both discrete. Would it be right to say that the (Z,W) distribution is $P(Z\leq z | W= 0)P(Z\leq z | W= 1)$?

Comment: What happens to $W$ if $X = Y$?. Moreover are X and Y independent, at least when you consider them exponentially distributed?

Comment: @Kore-N Sorry. I forgot to add that $X,Y$ are independent.

Comment: Then I would say that your formulas are substantially correct, but $P(X \le Y)$ should have $x$ replaced by $y$ in the integration (guess it's a typo). And in general you know that $P(A, B) = P(A |B) P(B)$ simply from the definition. So $P(Z = z, W = w) = P(Z = z | W = w) P(W = w).$

Comment: But isn't $P(W=w)=0?$

Comment: $P(W=w)$ is not zero for $w=0$ or $w=1$, which are the only two cases of interest. On the other hand since $Z$ is continuous $P(Z = z)$ is certainly zero. So either you interpret this as a probability *density*, or as you did, you use the formula for $Z \le z$ instead of  $Z = z.$ In this way you aim at characterizing the joint law through the *cumulative probability function*.

Comment: @Kore-N First I would like to apologize, but I think I'm not getting it...

I have expressions for $P(Z\leq z| W=0)$ and $P(Z\leq z| W=1)$ which I calculated using the integrals above (applying the corrections you mentioned in your first comment).

Now, the joint distribution I am looking for is it $P(Z\leq z, W\leq w)?$ W is discrete, Can't I use both case I calculated before? This is a solution that involves $P(Z\leq z, W=0)$ and $P(Z\leq z, W=1)$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65609/discussion-between-kore-n-and-cure).